# Loop to replicate values into an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I’m in a situation where I need to reproduce something in VBA and a bit stuck given my lack of understanding of object oriented language and VBA in general.

*Problem*:

- I need to produce an array or vector based on a 2 column table.
- The first range (column) contains unit counts.
- The second range (column) contains numeric values.

I need to replicate the value based on the number of units.

For example,

> if the first row contains 3 units with a value of $100
>    I need the array to contain $100, $100, $100.
>    This will need to be looped thru each row containing units.
>     So if row 2 contains 2 units with a value of $50
>     I need to complete array to be $100, $100, $100, $50, $50, and so on.

I understand this situation will require ReDim the array based on the total values.  My struggle is I’ve been unable to figure out the nested for loops.

I get how to replicate the value based on the number of “units” like the below...

```
    ReDim arr(0 To x - 1)
    For i = 0 To x - 1
    arr(i) = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
```

What is the best way to loop thru each row and replicate the values for each row in the range based on the unit count?

If anyone is familiar with R, I'm essentially looking for something that achieves the rep() function (e.g., rep(df$b, df$a)) and return the values in a single array.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Or a one liner which uses the `REPT` function as you would have used in [r](/questions/tagged/r) :)

This assumes your data is in `A1:B10` - the length can be made variable

`s = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("=INDEx(REPT(B1:B10&"","",A1:A10),,1)"))), ",")`

An an example, to dump the new to array to C1

```
s = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("=INDEx(REPT(B1:B10&"","",A1:A10),,1)"))), ",")
[c1].Resize(UBound(s), 1) = Application.Transpose(s)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you say `Row contains 3 units`, do you mean the cell has value `3` or `3 Units`? If it is `3` then you may not have to `Redim` the array in the loop. Simply find the sum of values in Col A which has units and `Redim` it in one go as shown below.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ar() As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet6

    With ws
        n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Columns(1))

        ReDim Ar(t To n)

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        n = 1

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                For j = 1 To .Range("A" & i).Value
                    Ar(n) = .Range("B" & i).Value
                    n = n + 1
                Next j
            End If
        Next i

        For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
            Debug.Print Ar(i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

And if the cell has `3 Units` then you will have to store the values of Col A in an array, do a replace on `Unit/Units`, find the sum and finally use the above code. Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ar() As String, tmpAr As Variant
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet6

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        tmpAr = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value

        For i = LBound(tmpAr) To UBound(tmpAr)
            tmpAr(i, 1) = Replace(tmpAr(i, 1), "Units", "")
            tmpAr(i, 1) = Trim(Replace(tmpAr(i, 1), "Unit", ""))

            n = n + Val(tmpAr(i, 1))
        Next i

        ReDim Ar(t To n)

        n = 1

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                k = Val(Trim(Replace(Replace(.Range("A" & i).Value, "Units", ""), "Unit", "")))

                For j = 1 To k
                    Ar(n) = .Range("B" & i).Value
                    n = n + 1
                Next j
            End If
        Next i

        For i = 1 To UBound(Ar)
            Debug.Print Ar(i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your data is already in an array then `ReDim`'ing will delete it's contents. You can `ReDim Preserve` but it's an expensive operation, better to create a new array to put the results into.

I have assumed the data is contained within a Named Range called `"Data"` with `Units` being the first column and `Values` being the second column.

if your data changes regularly you can create a dynamic range using the `OFFSET` function i.e. `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),2)` assuming your data starts in cell `A1` and there is no header row.

```
Sub ProcessData()

    Dim DataArr() As Variant
    Dim QtyColArr() As Variant
    Dim ResultArr() As Variant
    Dim TotalQty As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    'store data into array
    DataArr = Range("Data") 'assume data stored in named range called "Data"

    'store Qty col into 1D array
    QtyColArr = Range("Data").Resize(, 1)

    'sum all qty vals
    TotalQty = Application.Sum(QtyColArr)

    're-size ResultsArray
    ReDim ResultArr(1 To TotalQty)

    'Initialize ResultsArr counter
    k = LBound(ResultArr)

    'loop DataArr
    For i = LBound(DataArr) To UBound(DataArr)

        'loop qty for current row
        For j = 1 To DataArr(i, 1)

            'copy  value
            ResultArr(k) = DataArr(i, 2)

            'iterate ResultsArr counter
            k = k + 1

        Next j

    Next i

    'output to intermediate window
    Debug.Print "{" & Join(ResultArr) & "}"

End Sub
```